# find & cp command doesn't copy 1st level directory

Tags: find, directory, cp, file-copy

I have a directory structure like this:

```
test folders
├── 1
│   ├── 1-1
│   ├── 1-2
│   └── 1-3
├── 2
│   ├── 2-1
│   ├── 2-2
│   └── 2-3
├── 3
│   ├── 3-1
│   ├── 3-2
│   └── 3-3
└── 4
    ├── 4-1
    ├── 4-2
    └── 4-3

16 directories, 0 files
```

and I am struggling with copying ONLY the 1st level folders -- 1,2,3,4 excluding all subfolders using find & cp commands

```
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
└── 4
```

working directory is: "/home/username/Downloads/test folders"

I used

```
username@username-desktop:~/Downloads/test folders$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

and the output is

```
.
./2
./3
./4
./1
```

If I combine the 1st part of the command with cp: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec cp -p -v "{}" "/home/username/Downloads/results" \;` then the result is:

```
username@username-desktop:~/Downloads/test folders$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec cp -p -v "{}" "/home/username/Downloads/results" \;
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '.'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './2'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './3'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './4'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory './1'
```

so then I added -r switch to the above command:

```
username@username-desktop:~/Downloads/test folders$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec cp -p -r -v "{}" "/home/username/Downloads/results" \;
'./1' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./1'
'./1/1-1' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./1/1-1'
'./1/1-2' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./1/1-2'
'./1/1-3' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./1/1-3'
'./2' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./2'
'./2/2-1' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./2/2-1'
'./2/2-2' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./2/2-2'
'./2/2-3' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./2/2-3'
'./3' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./3'
'./3/3-1' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./3/3-1'
'./3/3-2' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./3/3-2'
'./3/3-3' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./3/3-3'
'./4' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./4'
'./4/4-1' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./4/4-1'
'./4/4-2' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./4/4-2'
'./4/4-3' -> '/home/username/Downloads/results/./4/4-3'
```

so now the results folder has:

```
results
├── 1
│   ├── 1-1
│   ├── 1-2
│   └── 1-3
├── 2
│   ├── 2-1
│   ├── 2-2
│   └── 2-3
├── 3
│   ├── 3-1
│   ├── 3-2
│   └── 3-3
└── 4
    ├── 4-1
    ├── 4-2
    └── 4-3
```

How is this copying all the subfolders ? even though I included -r but I also included - maxdepth 1 from the beginning in the find command. How do I make sense of why this is happening?

[edit] A follow up question is linked to here: [How to exclude different levels of subdirectories with cp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762088/how-to-exclude-different-levels-of-subdirectories-with-cp)

Comment: `-madepth 1` is only going to affect `find`, it won't have anything to do with `cp -r`

Comment: Try "man cp" and read what `-r` does.

Answer (score 1):

`-maxdepth 1` is a directive for `find`. Because of it your `find` will run `cp …` for `./1` and it won't run `cp …` for `./1/1-1`; and so on. Note it will run `cp …` for `.` in the first place.

When your `find` runs `cp -p -r -v . /home/username/Downloads/results`, the `cp` does not care about `-maxdepth 1`. *It only sees its own arguments.* And this exact command will copy `./1/1-1` because of `-r`.

See this: [*Understanding the `-exec` option of `find`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618). There is no magic, `find -exec` builds and runs standalone commands.

Comment: Ok I see...so then how can I copy nth level of directories with cp and find together?

Comment: @anmac1789 Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work. Your *explicit* questions were "How is this copying all the subfolders?", "How do I make sense of why this is happening?". I believe I have answered these. Asking a follow up question in comments does not fit the site. Editing your post is possible, but expanding it after it was answered is not a good practice. Consider asking a separate question.

Comment: my follow up question is related to the original question what do you mean ?

Comment: @anmac1789 The follow-up question is related, but answer(s) will be substantially different. I was able to answer the current questions, but *maybe* I cannot answer the follow-up. Other users may know answers to the follow-up and there is no need for them to duplicate my answer. In this case having two questions (i.e. posts, threads) is totally within the gist of the site; they will be related, we can link them, no problem. Having one post that covers all your questions may give you partial answers: my answer answers the original questions, new answers will answer the follow-up. Not good.

Comment: Ok, a new follow up question is linked to this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762088/how-to-exclude-different-levels-of-subdirectories-with-cp

I've edited my original post to let you know